# Should Thank You Cards be Written After an Acceptance or After an Educational Experience's Conclusion?

Tags: united-states, professionalism

**Circumstance:**

Recently, I received acceptance to a Certified Nursing Assistant training program and I plan on writing thank-you cards to the program director as well as each faculty member.

**Question:**

Should I have written the program director a thank you card immediately after she extended an acceptance to me or shall I wait until the conclusion of the program?

**Thought Process**

My reasoning is if I did the former all I could thank the program director for is the acceptance and possible future benefits and opportunities as a result of my completion of the program. Whereas, if I wait until the program's conclusion, I could mention specific skills I learned during the program.
Therefore, when I compose my thank-you card it might come across as more sincere and meaningful.

What is the convention/procedure on these sorts of things?

Comment: Don't know about a thank you card, but in my opinion it is totally ok for the students to chip-in and jointly buy the lecturer a bottle of fine single malt. After the final exam has been graded, that is. It is a mystery to me why my students never realized this.

Comment: I doubt that most of the faculty members had anything to do with selecting the applicants for a fairly low level and short (12 weeks or less) course. It was probably mostly a box-ticking exercise by the admin department. Sending "every faculty member" a thank you card for being accepted seems faintly ridiculous IMO.

Comment: @aleph I assumed they meant each of their instructors

Comment: For what it's worth: my reasoning would be exactly the same as what you write under thought process. I also believe that the recipient would appreciate getting such a card. As for convention (the actual question) I think the answer by Bryan Krause gets it right. But that of course makes it only more of a nice surprise for the recipients if you do write them.

Answer (score 25):

I don't believe it's necessary to write any thank you cards in this situation.

It's fine to thank someone who goes above and beyond or has a particular impact on your education, but I don't see that here.

A brief in person "thank you" is okay, but also not necessary.
It's also fine to say thank you as you accept. A card seems overboard.